# Regular expression to replace spaces with dashes within a sub string.

Tags: regex, string, replace, textmate

I've been struggling to find a way to replace spaces with dashes in a string but only spaces that are within a particular part of the string.

**Source:**

```
ABC *This is a sub string* DEF
```

**My attempt at a regular expression**:

```
/\s/g
```

**If I use the regular expression to match spaces and replace I get the following result:**

```
ABC-*This-is-a-sub-string*-DEF
```

But I only want to replace spaces within the text surrounded by the two asterisks.

**Here is what I'm trying to achieve:**

```
ABC *This-is-a-sub-string* DEF
```

Not sure why type of regular expressions I'm using as I'm using the find and replace in TextMate with Regular Expressions option enabled.

It's important to note that the strings that I will be running this regular expression search and replace on will have different text but it's just the spaces within the asterisks that I want to match.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What language/program are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To identify spaces that are surrounded by asterisks, the key observation is, that, if asterisks appear only in pairs, the spaces you look for are always followed by an odd number of asterisks.

The regex

```
\ (?=[^*]*\*([^*]*\*[^*]*\*)*[^*]*$)
```

will match the once that should be replaced. Textmate would have to support look-ahead assertions for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the other answer was incorrect wrong. I've tested yours and it does work.

Comment: Clever indeed :) although it would not work correctly if you would have odd number of asterisks in document. But anyway that doesn't make sense :) +1

Answer (score 3):

```
s/(?<!\*)\s(?!\*)(?!$)/-/g
```

If TextMate supports Perl style regex commands (I have no experience with it all, sorry), this is a one-liner that should work.

Comment: @Camsoft: This regex does not replace spaces between asterisks, but only spaces not followed/preceeded by an asterisk. It will not work for `ABC DEF *substring here* GHJ IKL`

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
/(?<=\*.*)\s(?=.*\*)/g
```

but it won't work in javascript if you want to use it in it, since it uses also lookbehind which is not supported in js

Comment: I did think of this but it gives this error (at least in PHP): Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length

Comment: interresting, i didnt try in PHP. Probably it has certain limitations to regular expressions. Of course it depends what regex interpreter one uses. Like i said, for example JS doesnt support lookbehind at all. I dont have/use Textmate so dont know if and how it is supported in it :)

Comment: It will also fail if there are two marked substrings in the string like: `ABC *This is a sub string* DEF *This is another sub string*`spaces around DEF will be converted too.

Comment: I'm trying to use the expression in TextMate but it's not working. Just checked TextMate manual and it says it does not support variable length lookbehind. Do you know any editors or languages that do support this type of expression?

Comment: @nobody yes, of course it will do that. Question is, is it a fail ? :) nobody specified what should happen under these circumstances

Comment: @Camsoft Hmmmmm i've tried in Expresso http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm , there it worked, that's why i've pasted it here

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `\s(\*[^*]*\*)\s`. It will match `*This is a sub string*` in group 1. Then replace to `-$1-`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regexp to get spaces from within asterisks
`(.)(*(.(\ ).)*)(.)`
Take 4th element of the array provided by regex {4} and replace it with dashes.

I [find this site very good](http://erik.eae.net/playground/regexp/regexp.html)  for creating regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your programming language but in many of them you can use lambda functions with your regular expression replacement statements and thereby perform further replacement on substrings.

Here's an example in Python:

```
string = "ABC *This is a sub string* DEF"
import re
new_string = re.sub("\*(.*?)\*", lambda x: '*' + x.group(1).replace(" ", "-") + '*', a)
```

That should give you *ABC *This-is-a-sub-string* DEF*.