# regex submatch replace

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I'm trying to replace all occurrences of a word but only when is placed inside a pair of delimiters. Example:

```
Original: asdf oldfoo asdf ("asdf oldfoo asdf oldfoo asdf") asdf oldfoo asdf
Desired:  asdf oldfoo asdf ("asdf newfoo asdf newfoo asdf") asdf oldfoo asdf
```

Is there any way to do it with **sed** or **awk**?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out this question: [Regular expression to replace spaces with dashes within a sub string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872705/regular-expression-to-replace-spaces-with-dashes-within-a-sub-string/6873023)

Answer (score 3):

If the delimiters are `'("'`and `'")'` and only one occurrence of the delimiters occurs per line:

```
sed -e ':begin;s/\(.*(".*\)oldfoo\(.*").*\)/\1newfoo\2/;t begin'
```

It does not work if you have multiple occurrences per line as the `'oldfoo'` in the middle bellow happen to be inside the outer delimiters:

```
asdf oldfoo asdf ("asdf oldfoo asdf oldfoo asdf") asdf oldfoo asdf ("asdf oldfoo asdf oldfoo asdf") asdf oldfoo asdf
```

If your delimiters are `'('`and `')'` , this works even if you have multiple delimiters per line:

```
sed -e ':begin;s/\(.*([^)]*\)oldfoo\([^(]*).*\)/\1newfoo\2/;t begin'
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, as @nobody mentioned, it's something like

```
oldfoo(?=[^"]*"([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

i guess you'll probably have to play with escaping of `"` a bit to make it work correctly with awk/sed

if you have perl it would be

```
perl -pe 's/oldfoo(?=[^"]*"([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/newfoo/g' whatever.txt
```

EDIT:
ok sorry, i didn't know that sed/awk don't support lookahead/lookbehind at all. I'm afraid that there is no way to do this task without at least lookahead.